# How to create a query based on fields of another queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have an app that saves Student quizzes using two models:
`StudentQuiz` saves the questions the student was asked
`StudentQuestion` saves the responses of the student for each of those questions.

```
class StudentQuestion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')  # comes from a Questions table
    answer = models.CharField("Answer", max_length = 100, blank=True, null=True)
    q_score = models.IntegerField("Score", blank=True, null=True)


class StudentQuiz(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField("Quiz Date", blank=True, null=True)
    total_score = models.IntegerField("Score", blank=True, null=True)
    ques1 = models.ForeignKey(StudentQuestion, related_name='q1')
    ques2 = models.ForeignKey(StudentQuestion, related_name='q2')
    ques3 = models.ForeignKey(StudentQuestion, related_name='q3')
    ques4 = models.ForeignKey(StudentQuestion, related_name='q4')
    ques5 = models.ForeignKey(StudentQuestion, related_name='q5')
```

I want to find the number of questions a student took in a certain date range for which he got a score of, say, 1.

So I create the first queryset:

```
quizzes_done = StudentQuiz(user=mystudent, date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date)
```

Now, I want to look at all questions that are in these `StudentQuizzes` and want to count the number of questions that have `q_score = 1`.

Currently, I am just looping over the QuerySet and doing this programmatically. But the QuerySet could be huge.

Is there a way to do this using django's DB APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the docs on [queries that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

basically, you should just be able to reference the `student_quiz` associated with your `StudentQuestion` object in a query on `StudentQestion`, filtering on `q_score` and user, and then use `__` to access the `StudentQuiz` properties you want (e.g. `filter(student_quiz__date_gte=blah`)

Comment: I have been trying your suggestion, but do not get it yet. I have a QuerySet of StudentQuizzes. Each StudentQuiz has 5 FKs to StudentQuestion. While StudentQuestion has no FK to StudentQuiz. So I cannot filter on StudentQuestion and look for the student_quiz__date_gte=blah -- right?

Comment: you actually can! From the docs "It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model." If you look at your example, it's similar to your setup-- Blog to Entry is a one to many relationship, where Entries have foreign keys to blogs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships is another good section on that page (though if I were you I might read from the beginning)

Comment: I did read the reverse relationship. I do not get all the entries. I guess that the part where I am probably going wrong is that there are 5 FKs to the same model. So probably just using model name is not enough?